# Medieval/renaissance superweapon

Tags: technology, alternate-history

Using the technology available at the time, what kind of superweapon could the medieval or renaissance age produce?

Comment: cannon and gun? its pretty much breaking the traditional warfare and making metal armor obsolete even destroy castle easily.

Comment: Anthrax scatter-gun, is that the sort of thing you might be contemplating?

Comment: Define "super".

Comment: We don't compile arbitrary lists. Define an evaluation criteria for the answers.

Comment: They did make [superguns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dardanelles_Gun#/media/File:Great_Turkish_Bombard_at_Fort_Nelson.JPG). Is that no super enough?

Comment: The question is clear. No reason to downvote it.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be something like a dragon (or other dangerous, trainable megafauna), which does not require any technology to produce, just a supply of dragon eggs.

Demons also work.